# How to send data from JQuery to C# Code Behind using Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get send an array of strings for the ID, and ints for the Display sequences to my C# code behind. I can currently cause breakpoints to be triggered in the function in the controller but my parameter in the request will always return empty.

Html and How Items are displayed:

```
                <p>Display Order</p>
            <div id="example1" class="list-group col DisplayItems">

                    @foreach (var x in Model.SiblingItems)
                    {

                        if (x.MenuId != Model.MenuItemId)
                        {
                            <div class="list-group-item filtered DisplayItem border border-black MenuDisplay" id="@x.MenuId" data-ParentId="@x.ParentId" data-MenuId="@x.MenuId" data-AppId="@x.ApplicationCd" data-MenuType="@x.Type">Display Order: @x.DisplayOrder - @x.Description</div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="list-group-item DisplayItem border border-black" id="MenuDisplayEdit" data-ParentId="@x.ParentId" data-MenuId="@x.MenuId" data-AppId="@x.ApplicationCd" data-MenuType="@x.Type">Display Order: @x.DisplayOrder - @x.Description</div>
                        }

                    }

            </div>
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    LoadList();

});

$('#btnUpdate').on('click', function () {
    var DisplayOrders = [];
    var counter = 1;
    $('.DisplayShown').each(function () {
        var displayItem = {
            MenuId: $(this).data('menuid'),
            DisplayOrderSeq: counter
        };
        counter += 1;
        DisplayOrders.push(displayItem);
    })
    


    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../MenuItems/PassThings',
        data: JSON.stringify({ values: DisplayOrders}),
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });

})

function LoadList() {
    var AppID = $('#ApplicationTypes').val();/*document.getElementById('ApplicationsType')*/
    var MenuType = $('#MenuTypes').val();  /*document.getElementById('MenuTypes')*/
    var ParentMenu = $('#ParentMenus').val(); /*document.getElementById('ParentMenus')*/
    var MenuID = $('#MenuId').val();
    $('.parentOption').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('appid') == AppID) {
            if ($(this).data('menutype') == MenuType) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })

    $('.DisplayItem').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('menuid') == MenuID) {
            $(this).show();
            $(this).addClass('DisplayShown')
        } else {
            if ($(this).data('appid') == AppID) {
                if ($(this).data('menutype') == MenuType) {
                    if ($(this).data('parentid') == ParentMenu) {
                        $(this).show();
                        $(this).addClass('DisplayShown')
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                        $(this).removeClass('DisplayShown')
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).removeClass('DisplayShown')
                }
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).removeClass('DisplayShown')
            }
        }

    })
}

$('#example1').sortable({
    animation: 150,
    ghostClass: 'blue-background-class',
    filter: '.filtered'

});
```

MenuItemsController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using static MyProject.Pages.MenuItemMaintenance.MenuItemsChangeModel;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class MenuItemsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PassThings(List<DisplayItem> values)
        {
            var t = values;
            return Json(t);
        }
    }
}
```